# How to import Winamp equalizer presets to Audacious?

Tags: audacious, equalizer

I just switched from xmms to Audacious and I'm trying to import the Winamp presets but without success so far. I checked various guides but none of them works. I have a file named `eq.preset` but If I try to import it to Audacious I get an error:

> Error importing Winamp EQF file 'file:///home/edem/winamp_presets'

I think that either this is a bug some people mentioned about Audacious or I'm using the wrong file. It looks like this:

```
[Presets]
Preset0=(WinAmp) Classical
Preset1=(WinAmp) Club
Preset2=(WinAmp) Dance
Preset3=(WinAmp) Full Bass
Preset4=(WinAmp) Full Bass & Treble
Preset5=(WinAmp) Full Treble
Preset6=(WinAmp) Laptop Speakers / Headphones
Preset7=(WinAmp) Large Hall
Preset8=(WinAmp) Live
Preset9=(WinAmp) Party
Preset10=(WinAmp) Pop
Preset11=(WinAmp) Reggae
Preset12=(WinAmp) Rock
Preset13=(WinAmp) Ska
Preset14=(WinAmp) Soft
Preset15=(WinAmp) Soft rock
Preset16=(WinAmp) Techno

[(WinAmp) Classical]
Preamp=-1.11022e-15
Band0=-1.11022e-15
Band1=-1.11022e-15
Band2=-1.11022e-15
Band3=-1.11022e-15
Band4=-1.11022e-15
Band5=-1.11022e-15
Band6=-7.2
Band7=-7.2
Band8=-7.2
Band9=-9.6

...
```

Since I'm using a rather new version (3.3.4) I think I'm using a wrong preset file. Can you help me out on this one?

Answer (score 2):

This is the winamp presets file edited for Audacious.
Save the following text as "**eq.preset**" in the folder "**home/.config/audacious/**"

**NOTE: lower preamp if your speakers are popping or else you will loose hearing.**

```
[Presets]
Preset0=Classical
Preset1=Club
Preset2=Dance
Preset3=Full Bass
Preset4=Full Bass & Treble
Preset5=Full Treble
Preset6=Laptop Speakers / Headphones
Preset7=Large Hall
Preset8=Live
Preset9=Party
Preset10=Pop
Preset11=Reggae
Preset12=Rock
Preset13=Ska
Preset14=Soft
Preset15=Soft rock
Preset16=Techno

[Classical]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=-1,11022e-15
Band1=-1,11022e-15
Band2=-1,11022e-15
Band3=-1,11022e-15
Band4=-1,11022e-15
Band5=-1,11022e-15
Band6=-7,2
Band7=-7,2
Band8=-7,2
Band9=-9,6

[Club]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=-1,11022e-15
Band1=-1,11022e-15
Band2=8
Band3=5,6
Band4=5,6
Band5=5,6
Band6=3,2
Band7=-1,11022e-15
Band8=-1,11022e-15
Band9=-1,11022e-15

[Dance]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=9,6
Band1=7,2
Band2=2,4
Band3=-1,11022e-15
Band4=-1,11022e-15
Band5=-5,6
Band6=-7,2
Band7=-7,2
Band8=-1,11022e-15
Band9=-1,11022e-15

[Full Bass]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=-8
Band1=9,6
Band2=9,6
Band3=5,6
Band4=1,6
Band5=-4
Band6=-8
Band7=-10,4
Band8=-11,2
Band9=-11,2

[Full Bass & Treble]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=7,2
Band1=5,6
Band2=-1,11022e-15
Band3=-7,2
Band4=-4,8
Band5=1,6
Band6=8
Band7=11,2
Band8=12
Band9=12

[Full Treble]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=-9,6
Band1=-9,6
Band2=-9,6
Band3=-4
Band4=2,4
Band5=11,2
Band6=16
Band7=16
Band8=16
Band9=16,8

[Laptop Speakers / Headphones]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=4,8
Band1=11,2
Band2=5,6
Band3=-3,2
Band4=-2,4
Band5=1,6
Band6=4,8
Band7=9,6
Band8=12,8
Band9=14,4

[Large Hall]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=10,4
Band1=10,4
Band2=5,6
Band3=5,6
Band4=-1,11022e-15
Band5=-4,8
Band6=-4,8
Band7=-4,8
Band8=-1,11022e-15
Band9=-1,11022e-15

[Live]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=-4,8
Band1=-1,11022e-15
Band2=4
Band3=5,6
Band4=5,6
Band5=5,6
Band6=4
Band7=2,4
Band8=2,4
Band9=2,4

[Party]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=7,2
Band1=7,2
Band2=-1,11022e-15
Band3=-1,11022e-15
Band4=-1,11022e-15
Band5=-1,11022e-15
Band6=-1,11022e-15
Band7=-1,11022e-15
Band8=7,2
Band9=7,2

[Pop]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=-1,6
Band1=4,8
Band2=7,2
Band3=8
Band4=5,6
Band5=-1,11022e-15
Band6=-2,4
Band7=-2,4
Band8=-1,6
Band9=-1,6

[Reggae]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=-1,11022e-15
Band1=-1,11022e-15
Band2=-1,11022e-15
Band3=-5,6
Band4=-1,11022e-15
Band5=6,4
Band6=6,4
Band7=-1,11022e-15
Band8=-1,11022e-15
Band9=-1,11022e-15

[Rock]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=8
Band1=4,8
Band2=-5,6
Band3=-8
Band4=-3,2
Band5=4
Band6=8,8
Band7=11,2
Band8=11,2
Band9=11,2

[Ska]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=-2,4
Band1=-4,8
Band2=-4
Band3=-1,11022e-15
Band4=4
Band5=5,6
Band6=8,8
Band7=9,6
Band8=11,2
Band9=9,6

[Soft]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=4,8
Band1=1,6
Band2=-1,11022e-15
Band3=-2,4
Band4=-1,11022e-15
Band5=4
Band6=8
Band7=9,6
Band8=11,2
Band9=12

[Soft rock]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=4
Band1=4
Band2=2,4
Band3=-1,11022e-15
Band4=-4
Band5=-5,6
Band6=-3,2
Band7=-1,11022e-15
Band8=2,4
Band9=8,8

[Techno]
Preamp=-1,11022e-15
Band0=8
Band1=5,6
Band2=-1,11022e-15
Band3=-5,6
Band4=-4,8
Band5=-1,11022e-15
Band6=8
Band7=9,6
Band8=9,6
Band9=8,8
```

Answer (score 2):

Following are the recommended presets for Audacious by Qaisar Nawaz.
save the following text as `eq.preset` in the folder `$HOME/.config/audacious/` (i.e., in `~/.config/audacious/eq.preset`):

```
[Presets]
Preset0=Classical
Preset1=Club
Preset2=Dance
Preset3=Full Bass
Preset4=Full Bass & Treble
Preset5=Full Treble
Preset6=Laptop Speakers / Headphone
Preset7=Large Hall
Preset8=Live
Preset9=Party
Preset10=Pop
Preset11=Reggae
Preset12=Rock
Preset13=Ska
Preset14=Soft
Preset15=Soft Rock
Preset16=Techno

[Classical]
Preamp=-1
Band0=-1
Band1=-1
Band2=-1
Band3=-1
Band4=-1
Band5=-1
Band6=-7
Band7=-7
Band8=-7
Band9=-9

[Club]
Preamp=-6.7199997901916504
Band0=-1
Band1=-1
Band2=8
Band3=5
Band4=5
Band5=5
Band6=3
Band7=-1
Band8=-1
Band9=-1

[Dance]
Preamp=-4.3199996948242188
Band0=9
Band1=7
Band2=2
Band3=-1
Band4=-1
Band5=-5
Band6=-7
Band7=-7
Band8=-1
Band9=-1

[Full Bass]
Preamp=-7.1999998092651367
Band0=-8
Band1=9
Band2=9
Band3=5
Band4=1
Band5=-4
Band6=-8
Band7=-10
Band8=-11
Band9=-11

[Full Bass & Treble]
Preamp=-10.079999923706055
Band0=7
Band1=5
Band2=-1
Band3=-7
Band4=-4
Band5=1
Band6=8
Band7=11
Band8=12
Band9=12

[Full Treble]
Preamp=-12
Band0=-9
Band1=-9
Band2=-9
Band3=-4
Band4=2
Band5=11
Band6=16
Band7=16
Band8=16
Band9=16

[Laptop Speakers / Headphone]
Preamp=-8.1599998474121094
Band0=4
Band1=11
Band2=5
Band3=-3
Band4=-2
Band5=1
Band6=4
Band7=9
Band8=12
Band9=14

[Large Hall]
Preamp=-7.1999998092651367
Band0=10
Band1=10
Band2=5
Band3=5
Band4=-1
Band5=-4
Band6=-4
Band7=-4
Band8=-1
Band9=-1

[Live]
Preamp=-5.2799997329711914
Band0=-4
Band1=-1
Band2=4
Band3=5
Band4=5
Band5=5
Band6=4
Band7=2
Band8=2
Band9=2

[Party]
Preamp=-5.2799997329711914
Band0=7
Band1=7
Band2=-1
Band3=-1
Band4=-1
Band5=-1
Band6=-1
Band7=-1
Band8=7
Band9=7

[Pop]
Preamp=-6.2399997711181641
Band0=-1
Band1=4
Band2=7
Band3=8
Band4=5
Band5=-1
Band6=-2
Band7=-2
Band8=-1
Band9=-1

[Reggae]
Preamp=-8.1599998474121094
Band0=-1
Band1=-1
Band2=-1
Band3=-5
Band4=-1
Band5=6
Band6=6
Band7=-1
Band8=-1
Band9=-1

[Rock]
Preamp=-10.079999923706055
Band0=8
Band1=4
Band2=-5
Band3=-8
Band4=-3
Band5=4
Band6=8
Band7=11
Band8=11
Band9=11

[Ska]
Preamp=-11.039999961853027
Band0=-2
Band1=-4
Band2=-4
Band3=-1
Band4=4
Band5=5
Band6=8
Band7=9
Band8=11
Band9=9

[Soft]
Preamp=-9.5999994277954102
Band0=4
Band1=1
Band2=-1
Band3=-2
Band4=-1
Band5=4
Band6=8
Band7=9
Band8=11
Band9=12

[Soft Rock]
Preamp=-5.2799997329711914
Band0=4
Band1=4
Band2=2
Band3=-1
Band4=-4
Band5=-5
Band6=-3
Band7=-1
Band8=2
Band9=8

[Techno]
Preamp=-7.679999828338623
Band0=8
Band1=5
Band2=-1
Band3=-5
Band4=-4
Band5=-1
Band6=8
Band7=9
Band8=9
Band9=8
```