# How to install Equilzer Presets in Audacious in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, sound, audacious

I have no presets for Equalizer in Audacious. How to get it and set user friendly?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not yet have presets for Equalizer in Audacious, then you will need to create some. The option "Output" - "Equalizer" reveals the "Equalizer" dialog. Tune the equalizer to your liking. You can then save the setting using the "Presets" button. This opens the "Equalizer Presets" dialog. Type a name for your preset, then click "Save preset". This is how you set and get presets for Equalizer in Audacious.

You can also export presets one at a time to separate files, or import a previously exported file by clicking the "Import" or "Export" options in the menu of the "Equalizer Presets" dialog.

Presets in your instance of Audacity are stored as a single text file `~/.config/audacious/eq.preset`. You could edit that file directly to add presets, but then you should be very careful to adhere to the correct format and structure of the file.

Comment: I want to use preset saved like this? Will this work? https://askubuntu.com/questions/326976/how-to-import-winamp-equalizer-presets-to-audacious#487037 Where to save and how to set this in 20.04?

Comment: I wish to set one of the entries in the answers in the above link in the last window in this link. http://pix.toile-libre.org/?img=1611313430.png

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect this case

Comment: For your first option, it doesn't appear for selection by a single click (on "Presets"). The dialogue window appears and all the items appear in that box. The Equalizer control changes only when I double click on the name. Doesn't it appear like a drop-box in "Equalizer" window? And for the second option, what is its file extension? The values in the above link doesn't suit to Audacious for 20.04. It varies from 12 to -12 like 12, 10, 8, ......-12 
http://pix.toile-libre.org/?img=1611322699.png

Comment: ........And (unlike the older version) I don't know whether there are 10 Bands on this latest version. I got this one also. https://redmine.audacious-media-player.org/boards/1/topics/2757?r=2758